# How to use the preChatinit method from the Live Agent API?

Tags: javascript, liveagent

I am trying to get the details passed from the deployment API into the pre-chat form so that I can store some of them on fields in the record that gets automatically created. The problem is that I don't seem to understand the usage of this method.

I added it to my JavaScript in the prechat form but I am getting an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: liveagent is not defined

**UPDATE:** I have fixed the error above by including the pre-chat API in the page but I still don't understand what's the correct usage of this method, what should be the "Chat URL" ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_accessing_details_prechat_API_preChatInit.htm

Comment: Might be of use to post the JavaScript with your personal removed; for example in the case of `clientkey = myclientkey123` you would instead post `clientkey = [insert-clientkey]`.

Comment: I just looked at the code on the pre chat form which has its own VF page that you need to assign/create. It appears the pre chat form sends an email when the "Request Chat" button is pressed. That causes a query to run to look for an existing contact. You can then input the results into the preChatnit method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got the answer from Salesforce support. Basically, the 'ChatURL' is the chat from the deployment API. The value can be obtained from the deployment code generated by Salesforce.

For example for:

```
liveagent.init('https://d.la2cs.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '27250000000xxxr', '00DR0000001tfff');
```

**Chat URL**=https://d.la2cs.salesforceliveagent.com/chat